# Show Targeted Content Based on Content Field and User Roles

Tags: views, users

I'm looking for a way to show specific targeted content based on a **content type's field** and **user role**.

For example, if user1 has a "Content Group 1" role, then the view should show content pieces with "field_content_grouping" == "Content Group 1". User2 having a "Content Group 2" role should only be able to see "Content Group 2" and so on. Both roles & field values are exactly the same.

I'm looking for the best way to properly execute this. I've seen people do similar things with pre-render for views or views query alter hooks. My general line of thinking is:

1. Before rendering views get User roles: Loop and check roles against a specific field "field_content_grouping" - if there is a match, continue else unset node from view.
2. Return full results (sans content pieces without a matching field &
   role).

What's the best way to accomplish something like this? Or am I completely on the wrong track all together? Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your *content field* a *taxonomy term* and you can accomplish this with a simple view without any custom coding.

If we assume

- vocabulary *Departments*
- user has field *Departments*
- some users with *department* selected
- [token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) and [views_argument_token](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_argument_token) installed

Add a content view

- Add any relevant filters (content types, etc)
- Add user relationship
- Add contextual filter *Has taxonomy term id*

  - *Provide default value > token* and fill in the current user's selected term id which in this case is `[current-user:field_department:target_id]`
  - use **Browse available tokens** to find the relevant token

Here is a screenshot of a working view

[image]

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention the module dependencies, updated the answer

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful! :)